# Spring boot oauth2 auth server sessions

Tags: spring-oauth2

I'm attempting to understand how spring boot uses http sessions to manage the oauth authorization code flow.

I understand that after the user submits their credentials via the /login form spring will persist the authentication object so it can be retrieved when the browser is redirected to retrieve the authorization code.

What I dont understand is if the browser needs to sends jsession cookie to the server or http basic authentication header when invoking this flow.

For example if I wanted to initiate the flow manually via curl do I need to specify any special headers ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use HTTP sessions to persist it, the client ID and authorisation code (the code that's passed back to the client app after the user authenticates) is used to identify the authentication object. The authorisation code is then used to obtain the access token.

So:

1. The client app redirects to the auth server, passing in their client ID.
2. The user authenticates with their username and password on the auth server , which stores the authentication against the code and client ID and passed the authorisation code back to the calling app as a request param on the redirect URL.
3. The client app calls back to the auth server, authenticating with it's client ID and secret and passing in the authorisation code. This is then swapped for the access (and possible refresh) token.
4. If the app needs the user details, the client app calls the user details endpoint authenticating with the access token it now has.

Comment: reg #2, where is the code stored? In Memory ? If it so how does it work in clustered environment

Comment: That depends: The default implementation you see in most the samples is in memory. You can switch the token store to one that persists to a DB though quite easily.